# AIX ssh issue unable to login

Tags: aix

I am unable to do ssh as normal users except root. I tried with password as well. It logs in successfully and throws me out .

Here is the error message I got.

```
unixadm@dmns03nim1:(/home/unixadm)>ssh -v msoidx
OpenSSH_6.0p1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Failed dlopen: /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so):   0509-022 Cannot load module /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so).
        0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

debug1: Error loading Kerberos, disabling Kerberos auth.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname msoidx: Hostname and service name not provided or found
unixadm@dmns03nim1:(/home/unixadm)>ssh -v gpmshost
OpenSSH_6.0p1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Failed dlopen: /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so):   0509-022 Cannot load module /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so).
        0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

debug1: Error loading Kerberos, disabling Kerberos auth.
debug1: Connecting to gpmshost [10.48.242.44] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/unixadm/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/unixadm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/unixadm/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/unixadm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/unixadm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/unixadm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 0c:4d:d8:43:2a:b9:f1:04:71:c5:15:41:17:0f:21:14
debug1: Host 'gpmshost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/unixadm/.ssh/known_hosts:209
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/unixadm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/unixadm/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gpmshost ([10.48.242.44]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Last unsuccessful login: Mon Sep 22 12:14:32 EDT 2014 on ssh from 10.48.200.4
Last login: Thu Oct  1 09:15:09 EDT 2015 on /dev/pts/1 from dmns03nim1


*******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************

AN ERROR OCCURRED DURING XGPMS1ST

CALL GE HEALTHCARE TO REVIEW THE FILE /gpms/gpms.errors
AND TO REMOVE THIS MESSAGE.

*******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************



********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
*****                                                                 **********
***  SYSTEM INITIALIZATION IN PROGRESS.  PLEASE WAIT WHILE IT FINISHES  ********
*****                                                                 **********
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to gpmshost closed.
Transferred: sent 3384, received 5808 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 12172.7, received 20892.2
debug1: Exit status 254
```

Can anyone  tell me what is the issue  ?

Comment: This is unlikely an `ssh` issue, your login was OK, however a program name "**gpms**" complain. most likely gpms is run through a source command, failed and call exit. log as root, edit `.profile` and fix gpms.

Comment: You may also check your `/etc/passwd` and see what shell does that user have, the problem could also be there if you are using a program instead of a shell...

Comment: i can't understand wht i have to edit in .profile , you mean t root profile file ?

Comment: i can see some users are using /bin/bsh shell , i tried as a user having korn shell

Comment: Did you mean `bash`? if that is the case then you should check your unixadm's home directory and look for `.bashrc`. Check what the script does, since it seems to be starting the program @Archemar states in his comment. Comment that line out if you want to test you can access ssh (to comment a line just add a `#` as the first character of that line).

Answer (score -1):

change your last line in `/etc/netsvc.conf` file to:

```
hosts=local4,bind4
```